# Adding bcd store entry to add in legacy win 2003 dual boot option

Tags: windows-server-2008, bcdedit

What settings to you use to add a legacy win 2003 config to the bcd store on win2008 server to enable the dual boot option. I tried to use easybcd, but I think it is a crock and it added a legacy boot.ini option which I don't think was their in the first place. I think it was {bootmgr}. Any help would be appreciated, as I am completely in the dark.

regards
Bob.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at this KB article; it was written for repairing non-working dual boot configurations, but it contains instructions to create additional boot entries for previous operating systems:

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/919529/en-us